# Resolving CORS Error in Laravel API for S3 Image Downloads without Modifying S3 Bucket CORS Policies

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, cors

To clarify my issue, I have an API built with Laravel. Within this API, there is a table that displays and allows the download of images. While I can see the images in my frontend, I encounter a CORS origins error when attempting to download them from the S3 bucket.

Unfortunately, due to the company's safety policy, adding CORS policies to their S3 buckets is not allowed. Hence, I need to find a solution that doesn't involve adding CORS policies inside the bucket.

The problem I'm facing is that I tried adding CORS to my API. However, in order to incorporate my route into the CORS middleware group I created for S3, doing so removes the entire component. This also means removing the other CORS setup I have for the backend (Laravel API) that is used in the frontend API.

How can I resolve this issue?

Here is my router:

This is the CORS route group for the API...

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
        Route::get('images/{uuid}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Web\Authenticated\API\ArchiveController@procesoImages')->name('archive-images');

});
```

This is what I attempted, but it didn't work because it interferes with the benefits of other CORS configurations:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {

...
});

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['AwsCors']], function () {
        Route::get('/archives/images/{uuuid}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Web\Authenticated\API\ArchiveController@procesoImages')->name('archive-images');
    });
```

Here is an example of the data structure:

```
 {
        "uuid": "asdasdasdasdasdasdaa",
        "nombre": "Apple Photo",
        "url": "https://abcdefg.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/applephoto.jpg",
        "created_at": "2023-06-15 19:07:08",
        "alias": "test",
        "updated_at": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "other-columns": "asdadasdasd",
        "type": 1
    },
```

I only need the URL to use AWS origins for downloading the images. The rest of the columns should use CORS for the API, allowing access from the frontend app.

I haven't been able to find a way to fix this issue. Can anyone provide assistance and share some ideas?

Comment: which webserver runs in front of the API?

Comment: frontend and api both runs on an aws instance / different url's.

Comment: and which webserver?

Comment: apache webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the way I make the download from frontend.

```
downloadImage(imageUrl) {
  fetch(imageUrl, { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.download = "image.jpg";
      link.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
},
```